# WinForms SQL Server CE Entity FW 6 - Does not save entity to DB

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I have a Winforms application using EF 6 and SQL Server CE 4. I have a simple DB first edmx model. Reading from the DB works fine but saving does not.

The save method is very simple:

```
using (var context = new ConfigEntities())
{
    Data line = context.Data.Find(1);
    line.IPAddress = txtIPAddress.Text;
    line.Port = txtPort.Text;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It happens in a separate form and when I do this save and open a form again to populate the text boxes, the data IS there. In the context. It just does not get saved to the local SQL Server CE DB.

Comment: You have to update your entity before saving your changes

Comment: Thnx. How? isn't line.IPAddress = txtIPAddress.Text; updating?

Comment: Have you looked for a copy of the database file in the bin/debug folder?

Comment: You are right. It is there. So why is the read from the project structure and write is to a Debug folder? How does that work? Every time I open the application my text boxes are empty. Please reply as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked for a copy of the database file in the bin/debug folder.

Possible solutions:

Do not include the database file in your project.

Do not use DataDirectory macro in your connectionstring, but set to fixed path, potentially at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating your entity its property, you have to define that your entity is changed ( modified ) using:

```
context.Entry(line).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

After that save your changes using `context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Thnx but it doesn't help. Could it be something about SQL CE?

Comment: do you have a try catch arround it? Maybe you have an error that is thrown